# Spring JPA Test java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to run the following test using Spring test 4.3 on Spring Core 4.1.4 (to test a Spring @Repository component) :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
public class POSUserDaoTest {

    private AuthCredential authCredential;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    AuthCredentialDao authCredentialDao;

    @Autowired
    POSUserDao posUserDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.authCredential = authCredentialDao.getById(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetByAuthCredential() {
        POSUser user = posUserDao.getByAuthCredential(this.authCredential);

        assertNotNull(user);
    }
}
```

And I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAllMergedAnnotations(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:126)
    ... 21 more
```

An online search on the exception yielded this result [Could not load test context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013452/could-not-load-testcontextbootstrapper-spring-unit-testing) but it was for an outdated Spring version (2.6), and I've also tried with spring-test version 4.1.4-RELEASE but maven reports there is an issue with the .zip file (probably the files doesn't exist in the repo or there is no such version of spring-test).

My **servlet-config** is in "/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a Spring version conflict. Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297356/testing-spring-jpa-repositories-non-spring-boot) for the answer.